# How to express type parameter bounds in methods?

Tags: scala

In Scala, I need to execute code that fulfills the following requirement:

Pass a `java.lang.Class` into a factory method. The class passed to this method must extend the abstract class `Project`. I will instantiate this class, perform various actions, and return it.

Here's what I have...

```
object ProjectFactory {

    def create (clazz: java.lang.Class[T <: Project]): Project = {
        val newProject = clazz.newInstance
        /* snip */
        newProject
    }

}

abstract class Project
```

...and here is the error I am getting:

```
identifier expected but <: found
```

I know this is just a syntax issue - how do I express this logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the type parameter after the method name, not at the use site:

```
object ProjectFactory {

    def create[T <: Project](clazz: java.lang.Class[T]): Project = {
        val newProject = clazz.newInstance
        /* snip */
        newProject
    }

}

abstract class Project
```

I'm not an expert with Scala's reflection libraries, but I think this might be cleaner:

```
object ProjectFactory {

    def create[T <: Project: Manifest]: Project = {
        val newProject = classManifest[T].erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Project]
        /* snip */
        newProject
    }

}

abstract class Project
```

That way you don't have to explicitly pass in a class object—you just parameterize the method with the type you want. Again, I bet there's a better way to do this, so I'd appreciate feedback from those with more experience in this area.

Also, I think Scala 2.10 has dropped Manifests in favor of ClassTags or something like that...

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
object ProjectFactory {
    def create[T <: Project](clazz: java.lang.Class[T]): Project = {
        val newProject = clazz.newInstance
        /* snip */
        newProject
    }
}

abstract class Project
```